# (C#) How can I make all these "else if" statements more condensed and how can I optimize my code better?

Tags: c#, if-statement, optimization, logic, statements

Okay, I have a load of `else if` statements, is there a way to condense them into fewer lines of code? Like make one if statement for all of it? And what ways could I make my code more optimize and easier to read?

````
            int x;
            int y;
            int time=0;
            Random rng = new Random();
            int hrand_num = rng.Next(-24000, 24000);
            int vrand_num = rng.Next(-24000, 24000);
            x = hrand_num;
            y = vrand_num;
            


            while (true)
            {
                ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
                
                 
                if (key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                {


                    y=y+2000;
                   
                }
                else if (key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)

                {

                   y=y-2000;

                }
                else if (key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
                {
                    x = x-1000;
                }
                else if (key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
                {
                    x = x+1000;
                }
                // Circumnavigate Players Position.
                  // North and South
                if (y >= 24001)
                {
                    y = -24000;
                }

                else if (y <= -24001)
                {
                    y = 24000;
                }
                  //West and East
                else if (x >= 24001)
                {
                    x = -24000;
                }
                else if (x <= -24001)
                {
                    x = 24000;
                }

                // Setting Time Zones

                if (x >= -2000 && x <= 0 )
                {
                    time = 0;
                }
                else if (x >=
                    1 && x <= 2000)
                {
                    time = 1;
                }
                else if (x >= 2001 && x <=4000)
                {
                    time = 2;
                }

                else if (x >= 4001 && x <= 6000)
                {
                    time = 3;
                }

                else if (x >= 6001 && x <= 8000)
                {
                    time = 4;
                }

                else if (x >= 8001 && x <= 10000)
                {
                    time = 5;
                }
                else if (x >= 10001 && x <= 12000)
                {
                    time = 6;
                }
                else if (x >= 12001 && x <= 14000)
                {
                    time =  7;
                }
                else if (x >= 14001 && x <= 16000)
                {
                    time =  8;
                }
                else if (x >= 16001 && x <= 18000)
                {
                    time =  9;
                }
                else if (x >= 18001 && x <= 20000)
                {
                    time =  10;
                }
                else if (x >= 20001 && x <= 22000)
                {
                    time =  11;
                }
                else if (x >= 22001 && x <= 24000)
                {
                    time = 12;
                }
                else if (x == -24000 && x <= -22001)
                {
                    time = 13;
                }
                else if (x >= -22000 && x <= -20001 )
                {
                    time = 14;
                }
                else if (x >= -20000 && x <= -18001)
                {
                    time = 15;
                }
                else if (x >= -18000 && x <= -16001)
                {
                    time = 16;
                }
                else if (x >= -16000 && x <= -14001)
                {
                    time =  17;
                }
                else if (x >= -14000 && x <= -12001)
                {
                    time = 18;
                }
                else if (x >= -12000 && x <= -10001)
                {
                    time = 19;
                }
                else if (x >= -10000 && x <= -8001)
                {
                    time =  20;
                }
                else if (x >= -8000 && x <= -6001)
                {
                    time = 21;
                }
                else if (x >= -6000 && x <= -4001)
                {
                    time = 22;
                }
                else if (x >= -4000 && x <= -2001)
                {
                    time = 23;
                }
 
                Console.WriteLine($"X: {x,6} Y: {y,6} Time: {time,3}");
            }   
         ```
````

Comment: search `switch statement`

Comment: `if (x <= 24000) time = x / 2000; else time = (24000 - x) / 2000 + 13;` will cut out most of it

Comment: @Charlieface You know that moment when someone throws some basic and simple math your way, and you ask yourself.... "Why did I make this so much more complicated...?" Only issue through is if x is 1500 then that would be ```time = 1500/2000;``` and that would cause some issues.

Comment: Quite right, it needs to be `if (x <= 24000) time = x / 2000 + 1; else time = (24000 - x) / 2000 + 13;` I think that covers all the cases. Also I think `else if (y <= -24001)` should be `if (y <= -24001)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using C# 8.0 you may have a look at the switch statement and switch expressions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression (additionaly the patterns documentation is also helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns)

So you could write something like:

```cs
switch (key)
{
  case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
    y=y+2000;
    break;
  // [...]
}

time = x switch
{
  >= -2000 and <= 0 => 0,
  >= 1 and <= 2000 => 1
  // [...]
};
```

Comment: Taking a look at them. So from what I am reading, it is say ```>=x and <=x => time```? Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: When I am using ```time = x switch``` it is giving me this message, "The switch expression does not handle all possible values of its input type (it is not exhaustive)." I am trying to figure out what that means.

Comment: It means that a case for the default value is missing. You could add `_ => 0` to set `time = 0` for all int values that are not handled explicitly by the other cases. This is the equivalent of the `default` case in a switch statement.

Comment: How do I know if I am using C# 8.0? I am really new to this...

Comment: This depends, if not explicitly changed, on your target framework, e.g. .NET 6.0. A listing of the default mapping between C# version and target framework can be looked up here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

Comment: This is not working for some reason, might need to find another way to do this.  I am using c# 8.0.

Comment: I got yours to work. However, I think it needs to be C#9.0.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you take advantage of:

- a [switch statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#the-switch-statement) for interpreting the arrow key

  - comparing the switch statement to an if loop, you can think of the first `case` as being the `if` condition and the remaning `case`s as being the `else if` conditions
- [`Math.Abs( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.abs?view=net-6.0) and [`Math.Sign( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sign?view=net-6.0) for circumnavigating the player's position

  - `Math.Abs( )` returns the absolute value of the variable; e.g. will `Math.Abs(x)` return `5` both for `x = 5` and `x = -5`
  - `Math.Sign( )` returns the sign of the value; if the value is a negative number, it returns `-1`; if it's a positive number, it returns `1`; if it's neither (0), it returns `0`. This helps us determine the wanted sign of the updated value.
- a [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) for setting the `time`

  - seeing as the `time` value alone is determined by `x` in the end, you can use a switch expression rather than a switch statement to determine its value. The switch expression says that you want to determine the value of `time` based on the value of `x`; and each following condition is compared to `x` (`<= -22001` is computed as `x <= -22001`). If the condition evaluates to `true`, the provided value is set as the value of `time` (`=> 13` then sets `time = 13`).

It could be implemented like this:

```csharp
int x;
int y;
Random rng = new Random();
int hrand_num = rng.Next(-24000, 24000);
int vrand_num = rng.Next(-24000, 24000);
x = hrand_num;
y = vrand_num;

while (true)
{
    switch (Console.ReadKey().Key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
            y += 2000;
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
            y -= 2000;
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
            x -= 1000;
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
            x += 1000;
            break;
    }

    // Circumnavigate Players Position.
    // North and South
    if (Math.Abs(y) > 24000)
    {
        y = -(Math.Sign(y) * 24000);
    }
    //West and East
    else if (Math.Abs(x) > 24000)
    {
        x = -(Math.Sign(x) * 24000);
    }

    // Setting Time Zones
    var time = x switch
    {
        <= -22001   => 13,
        <= -20001   => 14,
        <= -18001   => 15,
        <= -16001   => 16,
        <= -14001   => 17,
        <= -12001   => 18,
        <= -10001   => 19,
        <= -8001    => 20,
        <= -6001    => 21,
        <= -4001    => 22,
        <= -2001    => 23,
        <= 0        => 0,
        <= 2000     => 1,
        <= 4000     => 2,
        <= 6000     => 3,
        <= 8000     => 4,
        <= 10000    => 5,
        <= 12000    => 6,
        <= 14000    => 7,
        <= 16000    => 8,
        <= 18000    => 9,
        <= 20000    => 10,
        <= 22000    => 11,
        <= 24000    => 12,
        _ => 0
    };

    Console.WriteLine($"X: {x,6} Y: {y,6} Time: {time,3}");
```

I would also suggest introducing some constants; particularily for the value `24000`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You gave me things too look at. Hopefully the information you provide will help me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to cover all `time` cases

```cs
var time = x <= 24000
    ? x / 2000 + 1;
    : (24000 - x) / 2000 + 13;
```